# How do I connect my Mongo app to my site hosted on meteor.com. meteorjs

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This question has been asked before, but I didn't see any relevant answers.

I can connect to my mongo db by running meteor mongo SITE_NAME.meteor.com in the shell.
But I can't work out how to connect Robomongo to it. Running the above line tells me connecting to production-db-b2.meteor.io:/27017/SITE_NAME but entering that info into Robomongo with a username and password doesn't work. what should the username be?

Running meteor mongo SITE_NAME.meteor.com -U only gives me a temporary address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only get temporary credentials to connect to it.

When you run `meteor mongo SITE_NAME.meteor.com -U` you get the temporary address that will last for one minute. If you connect to it before the minute ends your session can last as long as you stay connected.

The url you get back would be in the form `username:password@b2.meteor.io:port/site_name`. You can use these details in robomongo if you can get them typed in and connected fast enough.

Every time you want to use robomongo again you have to get the new username and password and use that one instead.

If you can get a shell script to somehow connect then you may be able to write a script to extract the data out and connect with that using robomongo

At the time of this writing there is no other way to get credentials that last longer than a minute  for sites hosted on `meteor deploy`